# How does fscanf in c take in only 2 decimal places using %lf ? I tried %.2lf but it does not work

Tags: c, decimal, scanf

I've been trying to take in double value 1200.00 instead of 1200.00000000, this value needs to be put onto another file. But I'm unable to do so

I tried using `%.2lf` in my code like:

```
fscanf(file, "%.2lf", &items[i].cost);
```

But I am getting an error

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details about what you want to achieve. Maybe reading `1200.00000000` from an input file and printing as `1200.00` to an output file? `fscanf` converts the text representation to an internal representation, `fprintf` converts the internal value to a text representation again with chosen precision. The internal representation of a floating point number is the same, regardless of how many trailing zeros the decimal part has in the text input. Copy & paste the error you get.

Comment: `"But I am getting an error"` -- What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: The `fscanf` family of functions don't recognize precision specifiers in their format strings. Show us some code that we can test.

Comment: You need formatting for output (`printf`) and not for scanf.

Comment: Understand that floating-point numbers (`float` and `double`) are **not** stored internally as strings of decimal digits, with countable numbers of digits to the left/right of the decimal point.  They're stored in a quite different internal format (IEEE-754, usually).  The value you get when you use `fscanf` and `%f` to convert the string "1200.00000000" is *exactly* the same as the number you get from "1200.00".  How you print it back out is up to you; the internal format has no memory whatsoever of how many trailing 0's there were.

Comment: Even if you do restrict the number of digits input, for example with `fscanf("%4lf", &v);` any subsequent digits are not thrown away, but remain in the input buffer, and will be read at the next `fscanf` input. You must read the whole value given.

Answer (score 2):

The conversion specification `"%.2lf"` is not valid for [`fscanf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) in either standard C or POSIX — the dot is not one of the characters that can appear in a `fscanf()` conversion specification:

> Each conversion specification is introduced by the character '`%`' [CX] ⌦ or the character sequence "`%n$`", ⌫  after which the following appear in sequence:
>
> - An optional assignment-suppressing character '*'.
> - An optional non-zero decimal integer that specifies the maximum field width.
> - [CX] ⌦ An optional assignment-allocation character 'm'. ⌫
> - An option length modifier that specifies the size of the receiving object.
> - A conversion specifier character that specifies the type of conversion to be applied. The valid conversion specifiers are described below.

You aren't showing that you checked that your call to `fscanf()` succeeded — it should return `1` if it does.  The reading is not constrained by a field width (maximum number of characters to read), unless your library interprets the `.2` as equivalent to `2` (effectively ignoring the dot).  There isn't a way to limit the data that's read to 2 decimal places — unless the input data is a fixed width with leading zeros so that using `%7lf` will skip white space and read 7 characters for the number (`1200.00`), leaving anything else for the next input operation to process.  Remember that the `%a`, `%e`, `%f`, and `%g` conversions are interchangeable; they all recognize fixed format, exponent format, or hexadecimal format floating-point input strings.

You've also not explained how you get the output value `1200.00000000`.  That would typically be because you specified a [`fprintf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) conversion specification such as `%14.8f`, which prints 8 characters after the decimal point.

So:

1. Check the return value from `fscanf()`.
2. Show how you're printing the data.